Parallelization is not working with plan(mutlisession)
I'm using Rstudio server, I have 1To of RAM and 128 cores.
I'm trying to parallelize the function computeCommunProb for the package CellChat v2.
For that, as shown in their tutorial, I'm running plan(multisession,workers=100).
From what I understand, in htop, if the parallelization is successful, I should see multiple sessions (100 in my case). The problem is that I don't see them, I see only one session (one PID in htop), and I don't see 100 cores being used. It's more like one is being used between at 70-80% and 5 or 6 are used at less than 2%.
Is it normal ?
In my actual configuration, computeCommunProb takes hours to run I was wondering if maybe it's because the parallelization is not done properly. In the CellChat vignette they only used workers=4, can it come from that ? Because I'm using too many cores ?
I can't use multicore as supportsMulticore() returns FALSE
Thanks in advance,
Best

computeCommunProb() appears to internally test for future::nbrOfWorkers() == 1 on line 73. If TRUE, there's no parallelization but use of sapply.

future::nbrOfWorkers() returns 100, so I don't think that's the problem

Hard to say, but that function only uses parallelization for one part of the computation. That part may finish quickly on 100 cores, and the rest of the function is executed on a single core. You can run the function line-by-line to better understand what is going on.

Are you running this locally? Or are you attempting to do this on remote clusters?
